# How to choose the category and show the data related to the category?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to choose the age category and pass the value to another form to show the question related to the age category? Any better way to do this?

This is the Class

```
public string getquestion()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM category ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        //connection.Open();
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Label2 += rdr["Category"].ToString();
            }
            this.CloseConnection();


        }
        return Label2;


    }
```

This is the Home form

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Database category;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        category = new Database();
        Age_Category_Label.Text = category.getquestion();
    }
}
```

This is the Question form

```
public partial class Question_List : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Database question;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        question = new Database();
        showquestion();
    }
    public void showquestion()
    {
        string category = Request.QueryString["category"];
        string query = "SELECT top 10 * FROM question WHERE Age_group order by newid()='"  +category+ "'";
        if (question.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, question.connection);
            question.rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (question.rdr.Read())
            {
                this.Question_list_output.Text += question.rdr["Question"].ToString() + "<br />";
            }
            question.CloseConnection();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "SELECT top 10 * FROM question WHERE Age_group order by newid()='"  +category+ "'"  ? don't you want to compare the category with the age_group ?

Comment: no, i want to random the question depend to the category has been choose.
example there is 3 category let the user choose which is 1, 2, 3, when the user choose 2 then will random the question in the category 2 and show to the user.